# nuxt module configuration scoping

Tags: nuxt.js, algolia, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, meilisearch

How can I move the configuration key of a nuxt module inside the `runtimeConfig`?

The reason is I want to be able to overwrite configuration value (secret) from the environment using: `NUXT_API_SECRET`. This apparently only works for keys inside the runtimeConfig scope. But the scope for a pre-existing module is a some <> key. How can this <> key be moved inside the runtimeConfig scope?

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config#environment-variables

https://github.com/xlanex6/nuxt-meilisearch/issues/26

Comment: I tried all sorts a few weeks ago around ingesting ENV variables in Nuxt, I was convinced that the core lib is bugged in this area, that and some other unfounded issue made me scrap Nuxt and go back to Vue+Vite where I have no such issues.